# Extra line at the bottom of Chart using MPChart

Tags: android, mpchart

Can someone please tell me what is that extra line at the bottom of the chart with the "Description" text on the right bottom corner? How can I get rid of it?

I know the text can be removed by adding `chart.setDescription(null)`, but what about the line?

[image]